# How to fix htmlspecialchars() error in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I facing the **error** below in Laravel:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Which is appearing when I return data as `array`

```
$yAxis = array_reverse($data_array['counter']);
$xAxis = array_reverse($data_array['date']);
```

Instead of

```
$yAxis = collect($graphData)->pluck('counter');
$xAxis = collect($graphData)->pluck('date');
```

Actually, I can't return data as `collection` because I am modifying before passing to `view`, so how to pass an array or convert it into a collection to fix the issue.

I would really appreciate if you could kindly guide me. Thank you so much.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @CodeBoyCode yes this is the error

Comment: Why don't you show us how you are passing them to the view and how you are displaying it in the view rather than just saying that you are doing so?

Comment: Show your full view code please!

Comment: @JCode I have edited how I am passing it and in the view I am using in vue.js

Comment: you have not issue with your controller logic, may be you are using {{variable}} in view and not passing correct variable inside that

Comment: If you are returning array then you must have some foreach in your blade to loop through each element, please add whole logic and possible controller code to have better insight